Filebeat shows "Cannot index event" when there are indexing errors in Elasticsearch
When sending logs from Filebeat to Elasticsearch, when there is an indexing error, Filebeat will log the message
Cannot index event (status=400): dropping event! Look at the event log to view the event and cause."

There are no more details. I cannot identify the event log. The log doesn't show "reason" or "caused_by".
When I use Elastic Agent, this error shows more details, including "reason" and "caused_by".
Is there a way to achieve the same with Filebeat?
